# chemformula kröger-vink + pgfplots: Error when using dot notation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, chemformula

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{kroeger-vink}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            legend entries = {
%                 $x^2$,
                \ch{V_{Sr}^{''}},
%                 \ch{V_{O}^{..}},
                },
            ]
            \addplot+ {x*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When running the above MWE with the first legend entries everything works out just fine. The second entry using the `{''}` as negative Kröger-Vink notation works as well.

Trying to get the dot-notation (3rd entry) as a legend the typesetting is off respectively when trying to externalize the picture TeX throws an error.

I suspect this may be a problem of a nested tikz-picture as the dots in the kröger-vink notation are drawn via tikz in chemformula (?).

Is there anyway to get the desired legend entry showing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround you could just use a `\savebox`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{kroeger-vink}
\newsavebox{\VOOO}
\begin{document}
\savebox\VOOO{\ch{V_{O}^{..}}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            legend entries = {
%                 $x^2$,
%                \ch{V_{Sr}^{''}},
                 \usebox{\VOOO}%\ch{V_{O}^{..}},
                },
            ]
            \addplot+ {x*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice – the workaround works like an charm even when exteralizing the picture. I checked as the accepted answer and will award the bounty when possible.